# How to make log file user with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have a web page with PHP, Apache, MySQL runs on Ubuntu. My webpage has some function as insert, update, delete.

Now I want to monitor the operation of the web server by the user, such as write the log file when user login to the webserver and do something: insert, update or delete data.

How do I do that?

Comment: https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog, http://php.net/fwrite, store it in a database, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: So, how to detect action of user?

Comment: It's your code, how would I know? If you're capable of making the PHP **do something** you're capable of adding a line **after** that action to log it.

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Php stores error logs in /var/log/apache2 if PHP is an apache2 module. Shared hosts are often storing log files in your root directory /log subfolder. But...if you have access to a php.ini file you can do this:

```
error_log = /var/log/php-scripts.log
```

In Cpanel:

```
/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log
```

If all else fails you can check the location of the log file using

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

**Second Option:**

To write to a txt file and make a new one each day. Use date("j.n.Y") as part of the log file name.

```
    //Something to write to txt log
$log  = "User: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].' - '.date("F j, Y, g:i a").PHP_EOL.
        "Attempt: ".($result[0]['success']=='1'?'Success':'Failed').PHP_EOL.
        "User: ".$username.PHP_EOL.
        "Pass: ".$password.PHP_EOL.
        "-------------------------".PHP_EOL;
//Save string to log, use FILE_APPEND to append.
file_put_contents('./log_'.date("j.n.Y").'.txt', $log, FILE_APPEND);
```

So you would place that within your `hasAccess()` method.

```
    public function hasAccess($username,$password){
    $form = array();
    $form['username'] = $username;
    $form['password'] = $password;

    $securityDAO = $this->getDAO('SecurityDAO');
    $result = $securityDAO->hasAccess($form);

    //Write action to txt log
    $log  = "User: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].' - '.date("F j, Y, g:i a").PHP_EOL.
            "Attempt: ".($result[0]['success']=='1'?'Success':'Failed').PHP_EOL.
            "User: ".$username.PHP_EOL.
            "Pass: ".$password.PHP_EOL.
            "-------------------------".PHP_EOL;
    //-
    file_put_contents('./log_'.date("j.n.Y").'.txt', $log, FILE_APPEND);

    if($result[0]['success']=='1'){
        $this->Session->add('user_id', $result[0]['id']);
        //$this->Session->add('username', $result[0]['username']);
        //$this->Session->add('roleid', $result[0]['roleid']);
        return $this->status(0,true,'auth.success',$result);
    }else{
        return $this->status(0,false,'auth.failed',$result);
    }
}
```

One More thing you can do is:

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/php-error.log");
error_log( "Hello, errors!" );
```

Then watch the file:

```
tail -f /tmp/php-error.log
```

Or update php.ini as described in [this blog entry](https://perishablepress.com/advanced-php-error-handling-via-php/) from 2008.

For More Detail about error_log, You can visit this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe these links are also useful to you. [link](http://www.redips.net/php/write-to-log-file/)